# What Regex matches this String?

Tags: java, regex, string

How do I get the regular expression for this `String`:

```
$OK:COMMAND=4,45,,internet,,,60.210.45.68,1050,30,168.95.1.1
```

I have tried this one but it seems that it doesn't work:

```
public static final String commandMotif = "^\\$OK:COMMAND=(\\w){0,1},(\\w){0,1},(\\w){0,1},(\\w){0,1},(\\w){0,1},(\\w){0,1},(\\w){0,1},(\\w){0,1},(\\w){0,1},(\\w){0,1}";
```

NB : I can have some data between two comma but it can also be empty sometimes.

Comment: `{0,1}` means that `(\\w)` is repeated 0 to 1 times. `45` (and other parts of this string) has 2 `\\w`.

Comment: You really need to specify what can vary in the texts you're trying to match. Are there always the same number of commas? Is it always the same fields that have text, IP addresses, numbers?

Comment: And where have you matched periods?

Comment: #Dan Hulme : Fix String : $OK:COMMAND= and I have a fixed number of commas as the example and between two comma i can have a string or a number or IP@ or nothing !!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{0,1}`, you need `*`. `*` is repeating the previous element 0 or **more** times.

`\w` includes letters and digits and the underscore. In your example string there is "60.210.45.68", the dot is not matched by `\w`. You can add this by creating your own [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
public static final String commandMotif = "^\\$OK:COMMAND=([\\w.]*),([\\w.]*),([\\w.]*),([\\w.]*),([\\w.]*),([\\w.]*),([\\w.]*),([\\w.]*),([\\w.]*),([\\w.]*)";
```

`[\\w.]` is a character class matching a [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) or a dot.

I also moved the quantifier inside the capturing groups, so all matched parts between the commas can be found in a captured group.

If you don't need to capture the parts between the commas, you can shorten the regex quite a bit:

```
^\$OK:COMMAND=[\w.]*(?:,[\w.]*){9}
```

See it [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?36hj2)

Comment: `{0,1}` is not equivalent of `*` actually it is same as `?`

Comment: @anubhava, I didn't tried to replace `{0,1}` with the appropriate shortcut.

Comment: #stema : how to add a character class for IP@ to this Pattern ??

Comment: @AbdelbariAnouar, I added an explanation to my answer